# Missing property field after translation through Autodesk Forge Model Derivative

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a Revit file. In this file, there are multiple objects. These objects have metadata.
We have a Forge Viewer based application where we show translated Revit files. The translation is done by Forge Model Derivative.
I recently noticed that in the Forge Viewer, an object is missing a property value.

I confirmed that this object has the property when I opened the original file in Autodesk Revit application.
I also have separated the Revit object for more investigation. [Property missing Forge and Revit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tosDE.png) I will share the file when asked.

Comment: Please consider sending a reproducible model to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com, I will report  it to our engineering team. Note. Please remove any personal data from the any thing you want to provide before submitting, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported as **RVTLMV-1294 [Missing OmniClass Title value after translating]** to our engineering team to allocate time to do further investigations.

Therefore, please make a note of this number for future reference. You are welcome to request an update on the status of this issue at any time via sending an email to Forge Help email quoting this issue list item number. Thanks!